# passing objects to method of type CGFloat

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode, sdk, core-animation

Am I using the wrong types? CGFloat?  float?  int, all give me the same problem.

I need help with my method wiggleImage.  I am trying setup a method that I can  pass the objects in and have one method that I can call and animate many different views and reuse the code.  But when I hard code the anchorPointX, and anchorPointY values inside the method, it works fine.  When I use the values passed in, it does some strange conversion and as you can see from the log output, it changes the values to something other than what I am passing in.

```
 - (void)viewDidLoad {

 [self wiggleImage:candleFlickerView 
               duration:.45  
               curve:UIViewAnimationCurveEaseInOut 
               x:10.0 
               y:10.0 
               rotation:1 
               anchorPointX:0.2 
               anchorPointY:0.2];   
       NSLog(@"VDL  AnimationViewController....\n "); 
     }



- (IBAction)wiggleImage:(UIImageView *)image duration:(NSTimeInterval)duration
              curve:(int)curve x:(CGFloat)x y:(CGFloat)y rotation:(CGFloat)rotation 
            anchorPointX:(CGFloat)anchorPointX anchorPointY:(CGFloat)anchorPointY
{
// UN HIDE THE VIEW
image.hidden = FALSE;

// Setup the animation
[UIView beginAnimations:nil context:NULL];
[UIView setAnimationDuration:duration];
[UIView setAnimationCurve:curve];
[UIView setAnimationRepeatCount:FLT_MAX];
[UIView setAnimationBeginsFromCurrentState:YES];
[UIView setAnimationRepeatAutoreverses:YES];
//image.layer.anchorPoint= CGPointMake(0.5,0);
image.layer.anchorPoint= CGPointMake(anchorPointX, anchorPointY);


// The transform matrix 
 CGAffineTransform transform = CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(-0.45);
image.transform = transform;
// Commit the changes
[UIView commitAnimations];
NSLog(@"VDL showing wiggleImage Animation with Values of....\n ");  
NSLog(@"\nX=[%f]", anchorPointX );
NSLog(@"\nY=[%f]", anchorPointY );
NSLog(@"\nRotation=[%f]", rotation );

}


console output.
2011-10-07 10:21:54.580 Skippy[16932:c803] VDL showing wiggleImage Animation Values....

2011-10-07 10:21:54.581 Skippy[16932:c803] 
X=[2.562500]
2011-10-07 10:21:54.582 Skippy[16932:c803] 
Y=[0.000000]
2011-10-07 10:21:54.582 Skippy[16932:c803] 
Rotation=[0.000000]
2011-10-07 10:21:54.583 Skippy[16932:c803] VDL  AnimationViewController....
```

Comment: Holy parameter spew! This isn't C++. Why is wiggleImage an IBOutlet? This shouldn't matter just curious.

Also your console log messages don't match what I see in your code, are they accurate? Your logs should output those values correctly, only small issue would be that your rotation is probably seen as an int so there may be some conversion going on there.

Comment: Tried your code and it works fine for me. It prints the floats correctly.

Answer (score 0):

Is `wiggleImage` declared before it is used in `viewDidLoad`?  Make sure it is present in the header for your class, and that the header is included in the implementation file.